# Anatolian 'good': Indo-European or not?

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european, anatolian

The word for 'good' in Anatolian IE languages looks like this:

Hittite: *āššu*
Luwian: *wāšu*
Palaic: *wāšu* 'goods'
Lydian: *wiśśi*

I have seen so many questionmarks regarding it's Indo-European reconstruction, which make me wonder whether those words are Indo-European or inherited by a pre-IE substrate. I know Greek has ἐύς and Illyrian ves- (in PN Vescleves), but those are languages from the "neighbourhood". My question is: Do we have other cognates within Indo-European or is my substrate hypothesis plausible?

Comment: "The Sanskrit sú did not convince me." Can you give us more details why you find it unconvincing.

Comment: @AlexB. Is there a reason why h1oh1 > Ø in h1oh1s-u- (which is questionable)? Even if there is and I am not aware of it, I don't know if it would convincingly answer the question.

Comment: PIE *HC- > Sanskrit Ø; Greek e/a/o; Hittite a, h, Ø (Beekes 2011: 147).

Comment: I am not claiming anything but Slavic (eg https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/вещь) is superficially similar.  I cannot think of a cognate in Armenian but anyway it would be possible just a borrowing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE *h1(e)su- accounts reasonably well for ἐύς m, ἐύ n., as well as for Skt. su- and for Hitt. āššu-. The final -ς of ἐύς is simply the case ending for the nom. s.

The Luvian etc. forms look more like Skt vasu-, Av. vohu- and their cognates, IE *uesu-.

Comment: I remembered also the Illyrian personal name Vescleves, where vesu stands for 'good'. Do we have anything in Germanic, Italic and Celtic languages?

Comment: @Midas. Beekes mentions also Irish feb "eminence" < *uesu-.

Comment: There's also a [Gallaecian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castro_culture) name -so either Hispano-Celtic or Lusitanian, but in any case in the westernmost extreme of the ancient distribution of Indo-European languages-: [VESUCLOTI](http://hesperia.ucm.es/consulta_hesperia/onomastica/corpus.php?id2=1791), a [composite](https://books.google.es/books?id=BNyYAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA45) (gen.): < *wesu-kleut- ["(he who have) good fame"](https://ifc.dpz.es/recursos/publicaciones/26/22/06vallejo.pdf).

Comment: Correct link: http://ifc.dpz.es/recursos/publicaciones/26/22/06vallejo.pdf (p. 104).

Comment: @fdb Please update your post with the latest suggestions. I think we have enough parallels that speak for an IE origin. I would gladly mark this post as the final answer.

Comment: Also *h1(e)su- > Slavic su-, hence Russian _zdorov-_ "healthy" < *_sudorw-_